# Can I access discriminator field from php in doctrine2?

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an entity which defines inheritance like this:

```
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @DiscriminatorMap({"text" = "TextAttribute", "boolean" = "BooleanAttribute", "numeric" = "NumericAttribute", "date" = "DateAttribute"})
```

I am wondering is it possible to have getter for field 'type'? I know I can use instanceof (and in most cases this is what I'm doing) but there are few scenarios where $item->getType() would make my life so much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map a discriminator column to a field with Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284964/map-a-discriminator-column-to-a-field-with-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Extending what beberlei said, you could declare some constants in the Attribute class, and an abstract `getType()` function. Then, overload it in every derived attribute class.

Something like:

```
abstract class Attribute {
    const TYPE_BOOL = 0;
    const TYPE_INT  = 1;
    ...
    abstract public function getType();
}

class BooleanAttribute extends Attribute {
    public function getType() {
        return parent::TYPE_BOOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I'd do.

First, you made an `AttributeInterface`, to be sure that all future new Attribute types will implement the need method :

```
interface AttributeInterface
{
    /**
     * Return the attribute type
     */
    public function getType();
}
```

Then you create the `Attribute` abstract class implementing the `AttributeInterface` interface.

Use the constants in the `@DiscrimatorMap` call for some consistency

```
/**
 * Attribute
 * ...
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({Attribute::TYPE_TEXT = "TextAttribute", Attribute::TYPE_BOOLEAN = "BooleanAttribute", Attribute::TYPE_NUMERIC = "NumericAttribute", Attribute::TYPE_DATE = "DateAttribute"})
 */
abstract class Attribute implements AttributeInterface
{
    const TYPE_TEXT    = 'text';
    const TYPE_BOOLEAN = 'boolean';
    const TYPE_NUMERIC = 'numeric';
    const TYPE_DATE    = 'date';
}
```

Finally, you create all needed classes, extending `Attribute` class and implementing the `getType()` method

```
/**
 * TextAttribute
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TextAttribute extends Attribute
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this::TYPE_TEXT;
    }
}

/**
 * BooleanAttribute
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BooleanAttribute extends Attribute
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this::TYPE_BOOLEAN;
    }
}

/**
 * NumericAttribute
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class  NumericAttribute extends Attribute
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this::TYPE_NUMERIC;
    }
}

/**
 * DateAttribute
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DateAttribute extends Attribute
{
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this::TYPE_DATE;
    }
}

// And so on...
```

Comment: This doesn't actually access the discriminator field, it just pretends to. Consider a discriminator map which has multiple values for the same class, but you need the actual value from the database and not a guess as to which value it should be.

Answer (score 14):

It's possible either with the EntityManager or using the DocumentManager.

```
$documentManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))->discriminatorValue;
```

Answer (score 8):

My approach is to simply access it's value through the meta data doctrine generates

```
$cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
$meta = $cmf->getMetadataFor($class);
$meta->discriminatorValue
```

will give you the value, so as a method

```
public static function get_type()
{
    //...get the $em instance 
    $cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
    $meta = $cmf->getMetadataFor(__CLASS__);
    return $meta->discriminatorValue;
}
```

I cache the metadata in a static variable for each class that extends my base entity, there is a lot of other useful information in there as well ...

Answer (score 5):

No that is not possible, but you can do something like: get_class($object) == TYPE_CONST

Comment: What about cases when multiple discriminator values are mapped to same class? I'm migrating some project to Symfony and there are 5 types (class constants) mapped to 2 classes (hydrated by one database field, like discriminator). Other parts of code rely on `MappedObject::getType()` vs class constant comparison, so I need discriminator value or I have to refactor codebase with unique classes for each discriminator's value...

Answer (score 4):

There's a slicker way to do it in PHP 5.3:

```
abstract Parent
{
    const TYPE = 'Parent';

    public static function get_type()
    {
        $c = get_called_class();
        return $c::TYPE;
    }
}

class Child_1 extends Parent
{
    const TYPE = 'Child Type #1';
    //..whatever
}

class Child_2 extends Parent
{
    const TYPE = 'Child Type #2';
    //...whatever
}
```

Comment: Note that in php5.3 the `get_called_class` call is not necessary you can make use of the `static` keyword eg: `return static::TYPE`

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this if you want, like me, avoid use of const :

```
public function getType()
{
    $type = explode('\\', get_class($this));

    return end($type);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another slicker and faster way than to overload the method in every child or define a constant in every child is to use reflection class to retrieve the name of the class without the namespace :

```
public function getType() {
    return (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
}
```

It also works in any php version since php 5

It might not return exactly the discriminator name depending on your discriminator map declaration but it will return the child entity name (the class name) which is a great way to name and distinguish the different subentities

Without a need to define anything in the subclasses.

Comment: For my case this is the best method. I don't have a map set. And the type will be the lowercased class name. 

So i can out my images (files) into seperate folders like that: 


    public function getFullPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->getType() . "/" . $this->getFolder() . $this->getFilename();
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return strtolower((new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName());
    }