# PHP: Symfony2 Doctrine "The discriminator column "discr" is missing" HydrationException with filter

Tags: symfony, inheritance, filter, doctrine-orm

fellow programmers :)

I'm having a bad case of no idea what's going on.

This concerns two entities: `Ware` and `File`.
In my repository, I have a function that returns `File` objects along with wares to avoid lazy loading:

The relevant part of this function ( because the exception happens even if i trigger this bit only ) is this:

```
public function findByWithFilesTotal($params, $page = false, $per_page = false){

    $res = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT w, f FROM ShopBundle:Ware w JOIN w.files f');
    // same result occurs with LEFT JOIN
    return count($res->getResult());
}
```

Important stuff:
1) Ware and File classes are direct descendants of class Data. Discriminators are all right.

2) Ware has OneToMany relation with File - that means File table has ware_id column.

3) This is the most important part ( IMHO ). I use this filter to separate deleted items in all `Data` descendants.

```
class UndeletedFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {

        if(!$targetEntity->hasField('deleted'))
            return "";

        return "( $targetTableAlias.deleted = 0 OR $targetTableAlias.deleted IS NULL)";     
    }
}
```

It works for all the other entities, but causes a HydrationException with message 'The discriminator column "discr" is missing for "Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\File" using the DQL alias "f".' for this one query.

This, however, DOES NOT happen if I either remove `JOIN w.files` from DQL query, and leave it to lazy loading, or return an empty string from `addFilterConstraint()` method even if it does have the 'deleted' field.

So, if anyone knows: What exactly causes this, and how do solve it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: i didn't. had to keep JOIN w.files removed, since i found no other way of solving this.

Comment: Null values in table was my problem

Comment: The following answer could be of help on how to solve this.
[discriminator-column-to-a-field-with-doctrine-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284964/map-a-discriminator-column-to-a-field-with-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 3):

One reason for trigger this exception in when you are working inherent classes, then for example, if your `discriminator column` has `null` values the QueryBuilder will do not know how to convert this unknown type based in type.