# PUGXMultiUserBundle get type of current user

Tags: twig, fosuserbundle, symfony, pugxmultiuserbundle

How can I get the type of current user with PUGXMultiUserBundle ?
This code returns this error

```
{% if app.user.type == 'user_one' %}
//...
{% endif %}
```

This is the error

```
Method "type" for object "AppBundle\Entity\UserOne" does not exist
```

This is entity User

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user_one" = "UserOne", "user_two" = "UserTwo"})
 *
 */

abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

after updating database there is a new field named type created in table user

Comment: You don't have enough information posted...

Comment: @AlvinBunk , I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see the problem. In the twig file, you are calling:

```
{% if app.user.type == 'user_one' %}
```

Where "app.user" specifies the object, and "type" specifies the method. But you don't have a "method" defined in the Class. But instead you have the DiscriminatorColumn.

A method would be something like:

```
public function type(){
   ...
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I think that I must forget the DiscriminatorColumn and create another attribute.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284964/map-a-discriminator-column-to-a-field-with-doctrine-2?answertab=active#tab-top]

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so, you should upvote my answer.