# How to map type when map keys are not in the entity table with Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping, single-table-inheritance, discriminator

**Can the discriminator mapping strings of a Doctrine entity be fetched from a database foreign table field? If not, how to handle inheritance type mapping in such a situation?**

Considering a Doctrine 2.7.2 abstract entity `Person` with concrete entities `A` and `B` like:

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Table(name="PERSON")
 */

abstract class Person {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="name",type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

     /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="PersonType")
     * @JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $type;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="PERSON")
 */
class A extends Person {}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="PERSON")
 */
class B extends Person {}
```

A `Person` has a type bound to a `PersonType` entity like:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="PERSON_TYPE")
 */
class PersonType {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="code",type="string")
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @Column(name="name",type="string")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

**How to get the right class instantiated by repository query methods like `find()`, `findBy()`, `findById()`, etc?**

**Database set:**

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON:
id name type
1  John 1
2  Tom  2

SELECT * FROM PERSON_TYPE:
id code name 
1  A    Type A
2  B    Type B
```

**Expected results:**

```
$entityManager->getRepository("A")->findOneById(2); // null
$entityManager->getRepository("B")->findOneById(2); // B object (Tom)
$entityManager->getRepository("A")->findOneById(1); // A object (John)
```

I can't find how to specify this using a discriminator.

Alternatively I have a working solution implementing a SQLFilter with the inconvenience to have to enable or disable filter.

An alternative solution may be to [populate $discr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287525/2137266)?

(I can of course use the `Person::findByType()` method but it would be nice to have this feature directly managed by the respective repositories).

Comment: Can you share more details? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @NicoHaase is my question clearer now?