# Get current user type PUGXMultiUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm using PUGXMultiUserBundle and FOSUserBundle with symfony2.

My problem is i want to know the current user type in my controller,

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
// now i want to know the user's type for example
if( $user->getType() == "xx") {
 ...... }
```

of course the attribute type don't exist it's created by the PUGXMultiUserBundle in the datebase.

Comment: What is this dot notation for getter, like Java, are you sure about it? Why not '->'?

Comment: Also, using getter call inside if() usually or always does not work.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/17181541/1791606

Comment: sorry for the dot just a fault. for the getter inside if() i can just put the result into a variable and make the test