# Sonata - Dyscriminator field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I want to use my dyscriminator field in a datagrid filter and when i us this i have the error :
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'type LIKE :t': Error: Class Djoo\MyBundle\Entity\Structure has no field or association named type

Have you an idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doctrine will let you do that.

You can get discrimator value through metadata: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450381/can-i-access-discriminator-field-from-php-in-doctrine2)

But try using doctrine_orm_class to filter object by their class: [link](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html)