# Class Table Inheritance : Getter on Discriminator column

Tags: symfony

I'm actually working on a Class Table Inheritance. I would like to have, in my parent entity, which is abstract, a getter to access my Discriminator Column value. I mean getting the value in database and not just a guess of the value.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access discriminator field from php in doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450381/can-i-access-discriminator-field-from-php-in-doctrine2)

Comment: Hello, I saw this subject but I think it's not really duplicate. What I would like is access the real value in the database.

Comment: There's a strict answer posted by beberlei: **No that is not possible**. So take a look at workarounds proposed there and try something that will work for you.

Comment: Oh... Didn't saw it... Sorry !